# Как работает этот код

Tags: javascript

Всем привет!

```
window.location.search.match(/marker=(\w+)/) || [null, null])[1]
```

Этот код получает значение параметра marker, но я не совсем понимаю что означает эта конструкция  `[null, null])[1]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Именно такая строчка не будет работать. Не хватает открывающей скобки. Собственно любая похожая конструкция на js

```
(firstVar || secondVar)
```

firstVar, secondVar - может быть переменной, выражением, анонимной функцией, почти чем угодно. Если логический эквивалент первого выражения firstVar возвращает истину, то из скобок возвращается значение выражения firstVar, если ложь, то таким же образом вычисляется логический эквивалент второго выражения secondVar и далее аналогично с первым. Например:

```
function someFunction(arg) {
    arg = arg || true;
    console.log(arg);
}
```

Если в эту функцию someFunction не передан параметр, то консоль выведет true, если же аргумент передан, то в консоль будет выведено значение аргумента. 
То же самое и в [вашем случае](http://javascript.ru/String/match).

```
Если совпадений нет, то метод возвращает не пустой массив, а null.
```

То есть такая конструкция употребляется для того, чтобы результатом выполнения скобок был  в любом случае массив. Квадратные скобки [1] - 2 элемент массива.